# Is the sphere $S^2$ diffeomorphic to a quotient of the square?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, quotient-spaces, spheres

If we take the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and collapse the border, the resulting quotient space is homeomorphic to the sphere.

The same holds if we take the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ with the equivalence relation that associates $(t,0)\sim  ~(0,t)$ and $(1,s)\sim~(s,1)$ (poligonal topological representation of the sphere).

Any of these spaces are diffeomorphic to the sphere? If not, is it possible to obtain the sphere as any other quotient of the square in a differentiable way?

Comment: You need to decide on a differentiable manifold structure on a topological space before you can talk about diffeomorphisms between it and other spaces. How are you making these quotient spaces into differentiable manifolds>

Comment: I want to take the usual euclidean differentiable structure on the square in R^2 and on 2-sphere in R^3.

Comment: But you need a differentiable structure on the quotient spaces. Your quotient spaces happen to be manifolds, but they don't come equipped automatically with a differentiable structure.

Comment: You have to consider how the define the structure on the edges, but it is fairly straightforward how to do it, and the result is that both of these are diffeomorphic to the sphere. All you really need is show that each point is locally diffeomorphic (obvious except at the edges) and then the homeomorphism supplies the rest.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: well, the edges of the square have collapsed to a point in the first of the OP's quotient spaces, which complicates things a bit. However, the main point of my comment was that the question assumes there is a canonical way of putting a differentiable structure on a quotient space of a differentiable manifold, which is not the case. In fact, a quotient space of a manifold will not be a manifold in general.

Comment: This are not generic quotient spaces. They are very specific ones, and there are evident ways to define the structures on them. In both cases, the resulting manifold is a sphere.

Comment: But is it possible to obtain a parametrization of the sphere compatible with one of the quotients above (in the same sense of the usual parametrization of the torus from the quotient of the square)?

Comment: @PaulSinclair, that ther are evident ways to do it does not at all imply that the OP is aware of the fact that this has to be done somehow. Moreover, it is quite non-trivial to actually do it.

Comment: Take a sphere, and cut it along a half-circumference. The resulting manifold-with-boundary is evidently diffeomorphic to the square, with two edges mapping to one side of the slit, and the other two edges to the other side. His quotient is just the inverse mapping.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, well, a square is not, with its usual structure, a manifold with boundary as it has corners; for that to work you need to smooth the corners first.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez - that is a property of the "imbedding", not a property of the square itself, which is diffeomorphic to the disc.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, That is only the case if you put on the square a differential structure which already has has the corners smoothed. *How* to do that is not obvious.

Comment: You keep saying that X or Y is diffeomorphic to the square, but that **only** makes sense if you put a differential structure on the square. It does not have a "standard" one (its standard structure is one with corner, and with it it is most certainly not diffeomorphic to a disc), and you have not said which one you have in mind and, much less, you have bothered to give enough details so that the OP and other people with his question know about it.

Comment: Put the origin at the center of the square. Define $n(r)$ to be the distance from the origin to the boundary of the square along the line passing through $r$. Then $\varphi(r) = \frac{r}{n(r)}$ is a diffeomorphism between the square and the unit disc. As for the corners, place the origin at one and consider the map $f(re^{i\theta}) = re^{i2\theta}$. That provides *the* standard differential structure on the square.

Answer (score 1):

As Rob Arthan pointed out, to ask whether a quotient space $X$ is diffeomorphic to $S^2$ one has to define a differentiable structure on that space first.

An easy  way to define a differentiable structure is to pick a homeomorphism $\phi$ from  $X$ onto some differentiable manifold $M$ (a sphere in your case), and declare it to be a diffeomorphism: that is, smooth functions on $X$ are defined to be precisely the compositions of smooth functions on $M$ with $\phi$.

Of course, if you do *that*, the question of whether $X$ is diffeomorphic to $M$ becomes moot.

If you somehow define a differentiable structure differently, the search for diffeomorphism may be less trivial (it depends on your definition), but a diffeomorphism does exist. There are  [no exotic $2$-spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere).